# Testing a firebase function that gets triggered by a firestore event

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to test my firebase functions that run on certain firestore updates. In my tests I can set/update some value in the firestore that would trigger this function. Since my function also adjusts something in firestore, I can fetch the data from firestore afterwards, and check if it's correct. The problem with this is that (afaik) you can't listen to when a function has executed, so I don't know when I should fetch the data to see if it's correct.

Currently I just create a timeout of 4 seconds (very arbitrarily chosen), after which I check the result. I'm wondering if anyone else know a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: "Currently I just create a timeout of 4 seconds (very arbitrarily chosen)" => Where do you define this time out? In the function itself? In a test case?

Comment: In the test case. First I update the value in the firestore, then I create a timeout which checks the 'should have been updated' value